# prevent selecting past dates in timePicker DialogFragment

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I am applying the following code on an edit text to pick a date.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
{

    private OnDateSetListener listener;

    public DatePickerFragment(OnDateSetListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
{
    //do some stuff
}

void showDateDialog()
{
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(this);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "date_picker");
}
```

However, I want to gray out all the past dates so that the user won't be allowed to select any of them. Is this possible via code ? Or I should manually check if the date is a past date after selection ?

Answer (score 11):

Use [setMinDate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) function. It sets the minimal date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in [getDefault()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) time zone. Set the minimum date to today's date, so user won't be able to go past it. Something like following in `onCreateDialog`:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);  
DatePicker dp = d.getDatePicker(); 
dp.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
return d;
```

Comment: after almost halft year, yes this is the best answer! I don 't know why it 's still not upvoted.

Comment: I don't think that solution's meant to work with fragments, I could be wrong.

Comment: how can handle same in case of Dialog Fragment ?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with `TimePickerDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DatePicker.setMaxDate()` and `DatePicker.setMinDate()` to set a fixed year.

eg.

```
Calendar c_max = Calendar.getInstance(),
Calendar c_min = Calendar.getInstance();

c_min.set(2012,0,1);  // your min date boundary
c_max.set(2013,11,31); // your max date boundary

DatePicker.setMaxDate(c_max.getTimeInMillis());
DatePicker.setMinDate(c_min.getTimeInMillis());
```

As `setMaxDate()` and `setMinDate()` were added from API 11, you can do it as follows for the lower versions.

You can set range with init datePicker method.

```
// Calendar
this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
this.datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.your_datepicker_id);

// check for the build version
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // (picker is a DatePicker- set current time as min time.
    this.datePicker.setMinDate(this.calendar.getTimeInMillis());
} else {
    final int minYear = this.calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int minMonth = this.calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int minDay = this.calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    this.datePicker.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay,
            new OnDateChangedListener() {

                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int month, int day) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, month, day);

                    if (calendar.after(newDate)) {
                        view.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay, this);
                    }
                }
            });    
}
```

Comment: You cannot call DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker(); for api < 11. So your solution does not seem to work for api < 11

Answer (score 0):

```
date button on clcik method 

   dateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


            }
        });


for date piker create dialog method :

case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            {

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                final DatePickerDialog dojDPDilog = new DatePickerDialog(this,datePickerListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
                     dojDPDilog.setTitle("Select Date");
                try {
                    java.lang.reflect.Field mDatePickerField = dojDPDilog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDatePicker");
                    mDatePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        dojDPicker = (DatePicker) mDatePickerField.get(dojDPDilog);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dojDPicker.init(minYear, minMonth, minDay,new OnDateChangedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                              disableDate(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                              }


                        });
                return dojDPDilog;
            }  


for disable method:


      private void disableDate(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            if (year > maxYear)
            {
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            }
            else if (monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear)
            {
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            }
        else if (dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
            {
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            }
            else if (year < minYear)
            {
                view.updateDate(minYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            }
            else if (monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear)
            {
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, dayOfMonth);
            }
        else if (dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
            {
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
            }
        }



           and take local variables:

         int maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 100; 
    int maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int minYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int minMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int minDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this in the onDateSet() method. This is working for the fragments.

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar1.set(2014,11-1,11);
view.setMinDate(calendar1.getTimeInMillis()-10000);
```